# How can I make a PC enable Safe Mode automatically when it starts up?

Tags: windows, windows-10, cmd.exe, safe-mode

I am removing a virus, and removing the virus requires me to restart several times with Safe Mode enabled. But I don't want to install any programs (Just to be safe). I don't want to go through the trouble of enabling Safe Mode every time I have to restart. So is there a way to make a PC enable Safe Mode automatically when it starts up using CMD and if it can be disabled afterwards?

Comment: What have you tried?  Booting to Safe Mode just involves a temporary BCD entry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From CMD execute `msconfig`.
It will open System Configuration window and in the Boot tab you can choose the option to start Windows in safe boot. Choose the level that fits best for you.
Afterwards the procedure might have a slight difference to disable it. You may need to specify the exe whole path to call the utility.

Windows XP:
C:\WINDOWS\pchealth\helpctr\binaries\msconfig.exe
Newer versions of Windows:
C:\Windows\System32\msconfig.exe

Comment: @ Ronaldo I said from CMD. Please edit your answer.

Comment: @BrickMan, Thanks for explaining how to improve my answer.

Comment: @BrickMan, I believe the new answer you marked as the correct one doesn't work to configure the boot to previous mode from CMD as you requested. When in safe mode you need to specify the whole path to call the System Configuration utility. It has a useful contribution to the comunity, I agree, but it won't work the way back from CMD so it's not a complete answer to the topic question. Please consider that.

Comment: OK, I didn't realize that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This works on any/all windows versions:
Open the RUN command & type `msconfig` & hit enter.
Click the Boot tab & check the box for Safe Mode with Networking.
Hit enter & restart your PC.
Your PC should start up in Safe Mode every time now, until you go back into the System Configuration & UNCHECK the box.

Note: If you want to add the Safe Mode to your boot options, then while you are in Safe Mode bring up the Command Prompt & type this - `bcdedit /copy {current} /d "Safe Mode" -hit enter`
You should see something like "Successfully copied to BCD" or words to that effect.
This gives you the choice to boot regularly or to Safe mode, at every startup, even after you uncheck the box for Safe mode with networking.

This is just another way of saying the same thing as those before me, but in a slightly different way. "In windows there is ALWAYS three or more ways to accomplish the same thing". Plus I gave you the EASIEST option to add Safe mode to your boot list.

Comment: @ A G S  Both were really great answers, but I said : *... when it starts up **using CMD***. I upvoted your answer though